# retrieve or create an object

Tags: ios, objective-c

The method below is code from the free Stanford iOS 7 course, week 13. My question relates to the code in the `if else` clause. In the first part, it says `if(!matches ...)`, which I assume means that nothing was returned from the fetch request. However, when the instructor talks about the third part of the control statement, the `else`, he says, we're going to create the object if it wasn't found in the request and he accordingly creates that object with this code

```
photo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

However, if he's creating the object because it wasn't found, then wouldn't `if(!matches...` in the first part also mean that a match wasn't found. If not, what situation does `if(!matches` deal with?

```
+(Photo *)photoWithFlickrInfo:(NSDictionary *)photoDictionary
       inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Photo *photo = nil;
    NSString *unique = photoDictionary[FLICKR_PHOTO_ID];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"unique = ", unique];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!matches || error || ([matches count] > 1) ){
        //handle error

    }else if([matches count]){
        photo = [matches firstObject];

    }else{
        photo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    }


    return photo;
}
```

Comment: Testing if `error` is not nil is wrong. `error` can be non-nil even if the method is successful.

Comment: @Sebastian  It's valid.   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSManagedObjectContext

Comment: @CrimsonChris Where does that document say that it is valid? From [Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html): "Success or failure is indicated by the return value of the method."

Comment: @Sebastian I was looking at this...

_error_
If there is a problem executing the fetch, upon return contains an instance of NSError that describes the problem.

_Upon further research I found that the return value is really what SHOULD be used to determine failure. However, not all methods even have a return value, in which case inspecting the error is the only way to check._

Comment: @CrimsonChris Which Cocoa(Touch) methods has no return value and an error out parameter?

Comment: @Sebastian No Cocoa methods that I know of have no return value and an error out parameter. _My point was that it is possible, I've seen it in the "wild"._ Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @CrimsonChris In Apple APIs, `error` can be non-nil on success. So checking `if (error)` is wrong.

Comment: @Sebastian I'm sure it can, I've never seen it happen though.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Here you go: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10200420

Comment: @Sebastian I'm getting a nil error in your example. What were you trying to demonstrate?

Comment: @CrimsonChris This is getting off topic. I'm demonstrating that the `error` parameter is untouched. So if it is non-nil before the serialisation (which it is for me on 64bit Mac OS), it will be non-nil after the call. If it is nil for you, try `NSError *error = (id)0x1234;`

Comment: @Sebastian I bet it's because you aren't using ARC. Prior to ARC you needed write `NSError *error = nil;`. I never claimed that Apple API's would set your error to nil if the call succeeded.

Comment: @CrimsonChris You are right, I had ARC disabled. But my initial statement of "don't check `error`, check the return value" is still true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's doing something a little sneaky...

The first conditional is true when one or more of three conditions are met:

1. `!matches` checks if `[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]` returned nil.
2. `error` checks if the error was set (not nil).
3. `[matches count] > 1` checks if the array returned has more than one entry.

The second conditional checks the count of the array. This really should be `else if (matches.count == 1` because if the count was greater than one it would have been caught by the first conditional. If the count is zero then then this if will not be executed because `if (0)` gets evaluated as `if (NO)`.

The else will only ever get run if `[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]` returns an empty but NOT nil array.

Comment: Note the difference between a nil array and an empty array.

Comment: so what is a nil array? does it mean that `[[NSArray alloc] init];` hasn't been run?

Comment: It is the return value for `[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]` when it encounters an error.

Comment: You should read up on how nil is handled in objective c. It can get tricky in conditionals because nil gets evaluated as a zero.

Comment: @ChrimsonChris thanks, I guess I find it confusing because the condition also checks for `error`, so in effect, according to your comment about it being the return value, it's checking for the same thing twice?  I've read a bit about how nil is handled but it still hasn't gelled as I worked through code

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil That first conditional is checking the same thing twice (sort of). You should probably drop the nil error check.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil The most important thing to remember about nil objects is that you can call any method on them and they will simply return nil. In other languages (Java, C#, C++) trying to call a method on a null object will result in an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If the request and all are valid, there are just no items matching the request, then executeFetchRequest will return no error and an empty array.  Hence, `matches != nil` and `[matches count] != 0`

Comment: To clarify, having no records match the request is not an error.